# JavaFX TableView with different cell types and unknown size

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to create a tableview from various csv files that contain strings and doubles and an unknown number of columns.

With a few minor changes I was able to use the answer here to create dynamic tableviews: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2474328

Along with this, using the tutorial here I was able to create a table view with strings and doubles by column: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

However, since I do not know how many columns there are I cannot create a class defining what data I have and since I need to be able to sort based on doubles as well as strings, I cannot use the first solution which uses an ObservableList of StringProperty to define the data. Does anyone have experience with this or have advice for a route I could take? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real strategy here is to read all the data in as `String`s, and then to examine the data in each column to determine the type.

Then you can dynamically create the columns according to the detected type.

For the table's `items`, use a `List<Object>` as the representation for each row, and then use the detected type to put the correct type of object into each slot in the row.

Here's a quick example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DynamicTableWithTypes extends Application {

    private final Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+");
    // this could probably be improved: demo purposes only
    private final Pattern doublePattern = Pattern.compile("-?(([0-9]+)|([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+))");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<List<Object>> table = new TableView<>();
        String[][] rawData = generateTestData();
        int numCols = computeMaxRowLength(rawData);

        Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[numCols];

        for (int columnIndex = 0 ; columnIndex < numCols ; columnIndex++) {
            String[] column = extractColumn(rawData, columnIndex);
            types[columnIndex] = deduceColumnType(column);
            table.getColumns().add(createColumn(types[columnIndex], columnIndex));
        }

        for (int rowIndex = 0 ; rowIndex < rawData.length ; rowIndex++) {
            List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int columnIndex = 0 ; columnIndex < numCols ; columnIndex++) {
                row.add(getDataAsType(rawData[rowIndex], types[columnIndex], columnIndex));
            }
            table.getItems().add(row);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(table, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Object getDataAsType(String[] row, Class<?> type, int columnIndex) {
        if (type == Integer.class) {
            if (columnIndex < row.length) {
                return Integer.valueOf(row[columnIndex]);
            } else {
                return new Integer(0);
            }
        } else if (type == Double.class) {
            if (columnIndex < row.length) {
                return Double.valueOf(row[columnIndex]);
            } else {
                return new Double(0.0);
            }
        } else {
            if (columnIndex < row.length) {
                return row[columnIndex];
            } else {
                return "" ;
            }
        }
    }

    private TableColumn<List<Object>, ?> createColumn(Class<?> type, int index) {
        String text = "Column "+(index+1);
        if (type==Integer.class) {
            TableColumn<List<Object>, Number> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
            col.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleIntegerProperty((Integer)data.getValue().get(index)));
            return col ;
        } else if (type == Double.class) {
            TableColumn<List<Object>, Number> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
            col.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleDoubleProperty((Double)data.getValue().get(index)));
            return col ;            
        } else {
            TableColumn<List<Object>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
            col.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().get(index).toString()));
            return col ;
        }
    }

    private Class<?> deduceColumnType(String[] column) {
        boolean allInts = true ;
        boolean allDoubles = true ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < column.length ; i++) {
            allInts = allInts && intPattern.matcher(column[i]).matches() ;
            allDoubles = allDoubles && doublePattern.matcher(column[i]).matches() ;
        }
        if (allInts) {
            return Integer.class ;
        }
        if (allDoubles) {
            return Double.class ;
        }
        return String.class ;
    }

    private int computeMaxRowLength(Object[][] array) {
        int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            if (array[i].length > maxLength) {
                maxLength = array[i].length ;
            }
        }
        return maxLength ;
    }

    private String[] extractColumn(String[][] data, int columnIndex) {
        String[] column = new String[data.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
            if (columnIndex < data[i].length) {
                column[i]=data[i][columnIndex];
            } else {
                column[i]="";
            }
        }
        return column ;
    }

    private String[][] generateTestData() {

        // in real life, read from CSV file/database, etc...

        return new String[][] {
            {"A1", "B2", "10", "-5.3"},
            {"A2", "B1", "15", "12.6"},
            {"A3", "B3", "5", "10.2"}
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this sorts correctly:
[image]
[image]
[image]